# webkitAudioContext event

Tags: javascript, audio, webkit, webkitaudiocontext

I used  "ended" event to execute some javascript code on the end of playback for html5 audio.

```
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
 // code
});
```

However, i needed low latency and i decided to use the lowlag plugin
(http://lowlag.alienbill.com/ ), which uses webkitAudioContext for webkit browsers.

Is possible to detect when the audio playback has finished with webkitAudioContext?

Comment: it has no ended event like audio, but you can monitor the time and emit your own event when the time comes...

Comment: Thanks I found the working example here:http://updates.html5rocks.com/tag/webaudio    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
   alert('finished')
  }, buffer.duration * 1000);

Comment: that's cool as long as the song doesn't pause or stop early...